# How to redirect route with an extension on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes

I want to redirect from the old URL to the new one.

route/web.php:
`Route::get('/news.php', function () { return redirect('news'); });`

I get the error instead of routing:
*File Not found*

I think it's some of the silly mistake. But, what am I doing wrong?

p.s. I can't edit server configs.

Comment: It may be that your server config tries to send any `.php` extension to the PHP handler. Not unusual in, say, nginx. You could put a file in `public/news.php` that issues a redirect as a workaround, as you can't edit the config.

Comment: Why do you have a route with an extension? Just use '/news'

Comment: @ceejayoz it's good and simple idea! I will try it now.

Comment: Bülent Akgül, A third party service uses this address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the file public/news.php and it helped! ceejayoz thanks!